# converting a list object to a dataframe with two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list object "list" containing multiple lists with this structure below. All objects in the list have two letters like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "D"
```

I would like to convert it so that I get a dataframe with two columns like this:

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| C | D |

Is there a way to do this?

All of the examples I can find online are lists with one observation in each object, except this one that has labels in each list element:

[Converting a list of lists to a dataframe in R: The Tidyverse-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928743/converting-a-list-of-lists-to-a-dataframe-in-r-the-tidyverse-way)

Comment: In the post you shared the OP has an non-tidyverse to convert list into dataframe, have you tried that? That should work given your example.

Comment: I will look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to bind the list elements together in rows?
`rbind()`:

```
# mock up data:
obj <- list(list("a","b"), list("a", "d"), list("c","d"))

# binding:
df <- do.call(rbind, obj)
df

> df
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "b" 
[2,] "a"  "d" 
[3,] "c"  "d"
```

Then you just need to sort your column names etc in the usual manner.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few possibilities, let's first use base R and then also Tidyverse-way

```
# Option 1: Base R---------------------
# Don't use function names as identifiers, so I really recommend that "list"
# is renamed to sth like "multiple.lst" or sth. else. But will leave it for OP purposes.
list<- list(
  c("A", "C"),
  c("A", "D"),
  c("C", "D")
)

df <-
  do.call(rbind, lapply(list, function(x)
    data.frame(Source = x[1], Target = x[2])))

And the otuput:

  Source Target
1      A      C
2      A      D
3      C      D

#2 Tidyverse way------------------------
library(tidyverse)

df <- list %>% 
#  map_df: to iterate over each element of the list
  map_df(~data.frame(Source = .[1], Target = .[2]))
```

The output is the same as in option 1.